# VS Code: sync files from a remote *back* to local?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

Here is what I am trying to do:

I'm using WSL on a local Windows PC to SSH into a remote Linux VM. I have VS Code set up with remote-SSH, and I'm editing code and running debug sessions all in remote. Is there some extension or way to sync my remote changes back to local?

Basically, I am trying to do the reverse of what the Sync-Rsync or SFTP VSCode plugins do. The reason is because I can only run my code on the remote machine, and I'm not sure it's straightforward to develop locally, then do remote debugging from VS Code. After all, the official Remote-SSH plugin is to work directly on remote.

If this isn't possible, I suppose I can just run rsync on a local terminal to grab the remote changes. But ideally I could just have the Remote VS-Code open and do it all in there.